# ArcMap field calculator error 000989 indention error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I'm trying to make a four character output based on concatenating a single character field (in1) with either 1 or 2 zeros, depending on the length of in2, and then concatenating that . I'm getting an indention error on this but I can't see where. I looked at the other posts with this issue and none of their solutions are working for me.

```
def fixRouteName( in1, in2, out ):
  if len(in1) == 2:
    out = in1 + "0" + in2
  elif len(in2)  < 2:
    out =  in1 + "00" + in2
  else:
    out = in1 + in2
  return out 

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__

fixRouteName( !Exist_Partition! , !Exist_Route! , !Route! )
```

Here is the error message:

> Description The code block used by the Calculate Field or Calculate
>   Value tool has a syntax error. This error message provided will list
>   the specific Python syntax error.
>
> Solution This error code covers a number of Python syntax errors, for
>   example, Parsing error: unindent does not match any outer indentation
>   level (line 3).
>
> The above is a Python syntax error. Line 3 has invalid indentation.
>   For specific Python issues, consult the Python documentation for more
>   information, or consult the Calculate Field, Calculate Value, or
>   Analyze Tools For Pro help for more information on these tools.
>
> When returned by a script tool or when evaluating a script tool using
>   Analyze Tools For Pro, this error can also indicate that the tool's
>   source script cannot be found.

Comment: What are the field types of the three fields that you are passing values from into your expression?

Comment: @PolyGeo they are strings, text

Comment: Do either of `in1` or `in2` have null values?  If so, concatenating a NoneType and a string might give an error.

Comment: @PolyGeo no nulls

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?

Comment: Why don't you use python's str formatting? For example, `"{:0>2}{:0>2}".format(!in1!, !in2!)` would give what you want, say, `"{:0>2}{:0>2}".format("0","20")` will yield `0020`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code on my machine (running ArcMap 10.3.1) and it worked, so I could not replicate your error. Try using an `UpdateCursor` in the ArcMap python interpreter (substitute 'your_shapefile' for the name of your shapefile):

```
import arcpy
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('your_shapefile', ['Exist_Partition', 'Exist_Route', 'Route']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if len(row[0]) == 2:
            row[2] = row[0] + "0" + row[1]
        elif len(row[1]) < 2:
            row[2] = row[0] + "00" + row[1]
        else:
            row[2] = row[1] + row[2]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also, ensure both the input fields ('Exist_Partition' and 'Exist Route') are text.

On a final note, in your original function you passed `out` as an input, but you don't need to. The function need only accept two arguments. This is the function that worked in field calculator on my machine:

```
def fixRouteName( in1, in2 ):
  if len(in1) == 2:
    out = in1 + "0" + in2
  elif len(in2) < 2:
    out = in1 + "00" + in2
  else:
    out = in1 + in2
  return out
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. That makes sense and it works. I went for the second solution.