# ArcGIS pre-logic script code does not work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I am trying to define a function in pre-logic script code on ArcGIS 10.8. While running it, it shows the failure. I am not able to figure out the reason behind it.

I have defined the following function:

```
def no_mons(mon_in):
    if (mon_in<0.8 and mon_in>0):
        return 222
```

[image]

[image: Error screenshot]

The code block shows the following error-

`ERROR 000989 Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)`

Comment: Screenshot of Geoprocessing result?

Comment: It did change a few rows but not the all

Comment: if you input field is (integer,double,float) it should work correctly, i see no error in your code.

Comment: The input field is float, but its not wotking

Comment: than open geoprocessing result, expand the task, right click to the "Message" and check the problem occurred. If you havnt done already

Comment: It shows ERROR 000989; Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

Comment: Set environment extent to union of inputs.

Comment: @FelixIP not working

Comment: as i see your code, the if statement has more than one Space. Are you sure you are using a single space for indentation?

Comment: I have tried with different indentations, nothing works

Comment: No, you have to use just one space for indentation no tabs ore more than one space.

Comment: one space indentation also doesnt work

Comment: im testing it, it works. Open and close arcmap test it into another feature.

Comment: Check this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291721/arcmap-field-calculator-error-000989-indention-error